# time() not working in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

echo time(); gives me  timestamp 1293645728 which is a timestamp  of Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969 instead of current timestamp.

In my php.ini date.timezone="US/Eastern".I am using windows and thextension=php_timezonedb.dll , I have restarted apache several times .

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=timestamp+1293645728) says it's "6:02:08 pm UTC  |  Wednesday, December 29, 2010" How did you do your conversion?

Comment: Your timestamp is: Wed, 29 Dec 2010 18:02:08 UTC, you should check out site: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: This is my conversion date("D M j G:i:s T Y", strtotime(time()));

Comment: strtotime() is for parsing a stringified timestamp ("Dec 29 2010"), you're passing in the time() value, which is the numerical timestamp value. Strtotime can't do anyhing wit ha number, so it returns a false/zero, which then gets converted into your 1969 value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of

`date("D M j G:i:s T Y", strtotime(time()));`

just write:

`date("D M j G:i:s T Y");`

Answer (score 5):

> This is my date function .date("D M j G:i:s T Y", strtotime(time()));

strtotime is giving you incorrect results because a UNIX timestamp is an int not a string.  That's OK, though, because date takes an int, not a string:

```
date("D M j G:i:s T Y", time());
```

Edit:
In fact, this is redundant as [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) defaults its second argument to the value of `time()`:

```
date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp of 1293645728 is in fact Wed, 29 Dec 2010 18:02:08. As such, I suspect there's something wrong elsewhere. (i.e.: It's not PHP.)

For example:

```
<?php
   echo date('r', 1293645728);
?>
```

Comment: This is my date function .date("D M j G:i:s T Y", strtotime(time()));

Comment: @Aditya Shukla - The date function expects a timestamp - there's no need to wrap it in an additional strtotime. i.e.: Just use date("D M j G:i:s T Y", time()); :-)

Comment: you don't need to specifiy the time if you want date to use `time()`: `date("D M j G:i:s T Y");`

Answer (score 0):

0 is 1970 (beginning of unix epoch), 1293645728 is far from 0.
Your timestamp returns 12 / 29 / 10 @ 12:02:08pm

```
echo date("d.m.Y H:i:s", time());
```

What does it return?

Comment: Yes I am amazed.This what I am getting Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969.

Comment: Actually, 0 is Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 UTC 1970... which is the same as Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969 because EST is -0500.

Comment: Yes, just saw it was 31 Dec. That's OK but 1293645728 is far from 0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you converted the timestamp wrong, as Wolfram alpha gave me the conversion that you seem to be looking for: [6:02:08 pm UTC  |  Wednesday, December 29, 2010](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=timestamp+1293645728)

Did you do the conversion wrong?